# Issues with Separating Dataframe Using Commas

Tags: r, tidyr

I combined 30 text files into a data frame using the following code:

```
temp = list.files(pattern="*.txt")
myfiles = lapply(temp, read.delim)
```

The files are all set in similar fashion in a character string - Name, Gender, Popularity

For example:

```
Emma, F, 321
```

I am trying to create separate columns for Name, Gender, and Popularity and create a for loop that goes through the entire myfiles

I tried `Separate` but I am not sure how to include all the names

Comment: Why not specify `sep=","` in `read.delim`, e.g. `lapply(temp, function(x) read.delim(x, sep=","))`

Comment: If they are all comma separated, you might as well use `read.csv` instead of `read.delim`

Answer (score 0):

It's probably easier to get this all done with a one-liner:

```r
library("tidyverse")
map_dfr(temp, read_csv, col_names = c("Name", "Gender", "Popularity"))
```

This reads all files, creates separate columns based on commas, defines the names of those columns, and puts the result together in a single data frame.